# How can I delete an item from an Object in NodeJs/express/mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I know this has been asked before, but no one of the answers worked for me.
In my App, I have a users collection in MongoDb. These users collection have an array field named 'segActuacions' that can be modified within a form. This form sends this Object to router:

```
{
    "segActuacions.0.date": "27/09/2016",
    "segActuacions.0.body": "first item",
    "segActuacions.1.date": "27/09/2016",
    "segActuacions.1.body": "second item"
}
```

router has this line to go to controller:

```
router.delete('/seg_act_upd_EE/:id/actDel/:i', 
    sessionController.loginRequired,  
    userController.actuaDelete
);
```

where `':id'` is `User-id`, and `':i'` is the index of `segActuacions`

Controller has this code:

```
exports.actuaDelete = function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.id;
    var userI = req.params.i;
    var usr = req.body;

    delete usr['segActuacions.userI.date'];
    delete usr['segActuacions.userI.body'];

    models.User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, usr, function (error, user){
        if (error) res.json(error);
        res.redirect('/list_EE');
    });
}
```

I want to delete the fields `'i'` of the Object (for instance: `if i=0`, i'd like to delete `"segActuacions.0.date"` and `"segActuacions.0.body"`, ...but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking to delete the keys from the `req.body` object and subsequently update your collection with the remaining keys then follow this example:

```
exports.actuaDelete = function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.id;
    var userI = req.params.i;
    var usr = req.body;

    delete usr["segActuacions."+ userI +".date"];
    delete usr["segActuacions."+ userI +".body"];

    models.User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, usr, function (error, user){
        if (error) res.json(error);
        res.redirect('/list_EE');
    });
}
```

---

To remove the fields from the collection, the best way is to use **[`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#unset)** operator because `delete` removes the keys from an object and updating the collection with the updated object will not remove the actual fields from the collection.

In essence you use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to correctly identify the field to remove. For example, you would want to achieve the following mongo shell update operation:

```
db.users.update(
    { "_id" : userId },
    {
        "$unset": {
            "segActuacions.1.date" : "",
            "segActuacions.1.body" : ""        
        }
    }
)
```

This will remove the fields from the element in position with index 1 in the `segActuacions` array.

Tying all this with your controller method, you can construct an update object that is similar to

```
{
    "$unset": {
        "segActuacions.1.date" : "",
        "segActuacions.1.body" : ""        
    }
}
```

such as

```
exports.actuaDelete = function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.params.id;
    var userI = req.params.i;
    var usr = {};

    usr["segActuacions."+ userI +".date"] = "";
    usr["segActuacions."+ userI +".body"] = "";

    models.User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { "$unset": usr }, function (error, user){
        if (error) res.json(error);
        res.redirect('/list_EE');
    });
}
```

Comment: YES, finally it really worked!!! I was getting crazy between dot and array notations, and didn't think about quotes.."" Thanks a lot for your explanation @chridam

Answer (score 0):

Note your delete wouldn't work because you are using `userI` as a string and not using the variable value. Also update will just update the fields that are in the object.

But I think you should use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#unset), like the following:

```
var updateObj = {};
updateObj['segActuacions'] = {};
updateObj['segActuacions'][userI] = {};
updateObj['segActuacions'][userI]['body'] = '';
updateObj['segActuacions'][userI]['date'] = '';

var update = { $unset:  updateObj };

models.User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, update, function (error, user){
    if (error) res.json(error);
    res.redirect('/list_EE');
});
```

(This code can be improved and wasn't tested)

Comment: mmmm... it still doesn't work, but thanks for your interest @andresk

Comment: No, it doesn't. Just like before, nothing happens.